# Fading in a High-Res image after it's cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a best way to gracefully fade in high-res images with javascript/jquery after the client has cached it, similar to the way Bing or Yahoo Mail does it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the load function in jQuery.  Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){           
            $("#bigImg").load(function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="bigImg" style="display:none" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/2006-03-26_Denver_Skyline_I-25_Speer.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

And the jQuery reference:  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Happy coding!

Comment: There are some significant caveats detailed on the load-event page you have linked to. The behavior is inconsistent cross browser and it does not get fired for cached images, which is specifically what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I read the blurb from the jquery article you're referring to - they do list it as an issue.  I ran a test with firebug, and the image fades in perfectly fine when loading from the cache.  I kind of wish the exact scenario they're afraid of was laid out more explicitly.

Comment: After searching around a bit, someone already has an answer for workaround:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 1):

When preloading an image, I always do this :

```
newpic = new Image();      // create your new img
newpic.onload = function() // callback for when the img is loaded
{
                           // your callback, for you a .fadeIn()
};
newpic.src = your_img.jpg;  // Setting the img src will start the caching process
```

It works well.